# Collaboration / refererencing in the notebook environment (without Workbench)

Tags: notebooks

Discussing with my co-authors over the phone, I often find it hard to point out a specific input/line/part of a notebook. (I am not using Workbench)

The input numbering "In[1,...]:=" helps but updates and thus does not provide a stable solution. Also sections and text are useful, but I hope there is an even better solution.

Is there some functionality I'm missing in Mathematica, i.e. something similar to code line (input box) numbering?

Comment: Are `CellTags` ok?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is abandoned and needs a little of explanation from OP.